# Angular loads HTML index instead of ng-app.js on refresh

Tags: html, angularjs, node.js, angular-ui-router, mean-stack

I am playing around with adding in an Angular-UI router which is working perfectly when I click on links within my application. For example, if I go from `/` to `/feed/9` it will load in the `/partials/post.html` file into the `ui-view` div and I can then use the '9' held in `$stateParams` to populate the template with the data from post 9. However if I refresh the page, the site breaks and Angular tries to load index.html as the ng-app.js file? I have no idea what is happening here. I've uploaded some screenshots to demonstrate this and I've included my node server, angular routing and the relevant html partials. I have no idea where this is going wrong so I can provide any additional data and any help would be greatly appreciated!

Working fine when coming from another link on '/'
[image: Working fine when coming from another link on '/']

On refresh!!
[image: On refresh]

Node - server.js

```
var = /* Dependencies and vars */;

mongoose.connect(dbConfig.url, dbConfig.options);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser());
app.use(flash());

require('./routes/api.js')(app);      //For CRUD operations on the database
require('./routes/api_proc.js')(app); //Protected endpoints for CDN
require('./routes/api_ext.js')(app);  //For getting data from GCal, fb, Twitter and Instagram

/* The following code is a url rewrite to pass all
   further get requests that aren't defined in the
   above routing files through the index page and
   hence through the Angular 'frontend' routes */
app.use(function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});

app.listen(port);
```

Angular ng-app.js

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ngResource', 'ui.router']);

//Using state ui-router
// ROUTES
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
        url : '/',
        templateUrl : 'partials/home.html'
    })

    /* ... */

    .state('feed', {
        url : '/feed',
        templateUrl : 'partials/feed.html'
    })
    .state('post', {
        url : '/feed/{id:.*}',
        templateUrl : 'partials/post.html',
        controller: 'postController'
    })

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

});

app.factory("Feed", function($resource) {
  return $resource("/api/feed/:id", {}, {
      query: {
          isArray: true
      }
  });
});

app.controller("postController", function($scope, Feed, $stateParams) {
    var feed = Feed.query();
    feed.$promise.then(function(promiseData) {
        postArray = promiseData.slice(0,promiseData.length);
        $scope.feed = promiseData;
        $scope.id = $stateParams.id;
    });
});
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
    <head>
        <!-- CDN -->
            <!-- Angular, Bootstrap, Angular modules, etc. -->

        <!-- Styles -->

        <!-- Angular Script import -->
            <script type="text/javascript" src="ng-app.js"></script>

        <base href="/">

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>
    <body>     
        <nav><!--Bootstrap nav--></nav>

        <div ui-view></div>

        <footer></footer>
        <script>
            //For Bootstrap tooltips which are in some of the partials.
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip(); 
                $('[rel=tooltip]').tooltip();
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

/partials/post.html

```
<div class="container-fluid main-content">         
    <header class="banner" class="row">
        <h1 class="page-title">{{id}}</h1>
    </header>

    <!-- Main page info -->
</div>
```

Comment: try `src="/ng-app.js"`;  without the `/` you are telling the browser to load the resource from a directory relative to your current path, rather than the document root.  When you click links within angular, they do not force the browser to load a new page, and thus the `ng-app.js` isn't loaded again.  but when you hit the refresh or type in the url by hand, it does cause the browser to perform that search.  Better yet, don't store `.js` or `.css` files in the document root, but in their own directory to avoid this kind of confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have relative paths pointing to your css files.
When you load page from `/feed/9` then links are invalid.
Maybe it happens also for templates referenced from angular.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you! Changed `<script type="text/javascript" src="ng-app.js"></script>` to `src="/ng-app.js"` and it works brilliantly! Can't believe that's all it was! Haha